# Where can I obtain the Amtrak P42DC Genesis from Train simulator 2013?

Tags: steam, train-simulator-2013

I currently have the RailSimulator "Train Simulator 2013". I'm browsing through the Steam Store and finding player mods mentioning Amtrak P42DC Genesis. However I cannot find this on the Steam Store as a DLC add on or anything.

How do I obtain the Amtrak P42DC Genesis?

Comment: As of 23/7/2013,you cannot get the train as its link (along with many others) are broken

Comment: It's been unavailable on Steam since at least last December, it's not available anywhere else, so I'm afraid you're out of luck unless the company decides to re-release it.

Comment: @TZHX both of these comments look like answers, though TZHX's comment is more accurate. Perhaps one of you could post them as such? My research immediately yielded that same information, but since you've commented it already, I'd hate to snipe your rep and be accused of taking your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DLC you're looking for has been unavailable on Steam since at least last December and it no longer appears on the RSC website product list. It's not available through any other vendors (such as JustTrains) and so unless RSC re-release it, there's nowhere to get it from.

That it's been such a long time with nothing officially mentioned suggests this isn't going to happen soon (they usually tease their releases by quite some time). The most obvious reason is some legal issue with licensing the brand name, but that's speculation.